# Use the techniques from integration to find the volume of a cylinder of height h and radius r

Tags: calculus

I was thinking of starting with a quadrilateral or rectangle.
starting with a horizontal line a  $y = r$, then set the area under the curve by integrating from $0$ to $h$.
$y=r$ then $y = r^2$

$$\pi \int_{0}^{h} r^2 $$

how's this?

Comment: The problem with starting with a quadrilateral or a rectangle is that they don't fit the cross section of a cylinder which is a circle. So in order to find the volume of a cylinder you best start with a circular cross section and then integrate along the length. What you have written above is correct. You only need to integrate it wrt to height.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't have any plotting software with me but soon I'll show you Images that'll help understanding these methods

**Solution 1**

Assuming that You know that Area of Circle with radius R is $\pi R^2$

Now consider a disc (differential element)  of Radius $R$ and Thickness $dh$

It's volume will be $$ dv=\pi R^2 dh$$

Volume of cylinder can be written as $$V=\int_0^H dv=\int_0^H\pi R^2 dh={\pi R^2 H}$$

**Solution 2**

Assuming that you know that cirumference of circle with radius R is $2\pi R$

Now consider a cylindrical layer ( differential element ) at distance $r$ from center with thickness $dr$

It's volume will be $$dv=2\pi r H dr$$

Volume of cylinder can be written as $$V=\int_0^R dv=\int_0^R 2\pi Hr dr=\frac{2\pi R^2 H}{2}={\pi R^2 H}$$

If possible I'll add more methods.

Answer (score 0):

How about

$$\int_{0}^{h} \pi r^2 dr$$

$$= \frac{1}{3} \pi r^3$$

Comment: and you think that's correct result?